# not able to login to mysql

Tags: server, apache2, password, mysql

when I am trying to login to mysql using `mysql -u root -p` I am getting the following error

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have put root as my password while mysql-server was getting installed.

Comment: Either you entered a wrong password or you missed `PRIVILEGES`

Comment: try changing the host IP to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You can set a new root password with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.x
```

Replace x with the version you have installed.

Then try to log in again (if you put the password after the -p switch make sure there is no space between -p and your password, i.e. if your password is hello then you log in with mysql -u root -phello)

Answer (score 0):

*login* and *password* are in file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` under ubuntu 16.04 .